# ''My cousins learned korean there''?

Tags: vocabulary

Can I say ''my cousins learned Korean there''?  I am referring to a language center.

Is it **correct** to say that?

Comment: Ah, this is what's known as an anaphoric peninsula. _Korean_ is a language name that contains a country name, and it is therefore available as an antecedent for a toponym. But you couldn't say **My cousin learned  Minangkabau there,* because _Minangkabau_ names an ethnic group and language, but not an area. Anaphoric peninsulas are exceptions to anaphoric islands like **He's an orphan, and he misses them*.

Comment: Well, @John, what you say makes sense, but I'm not sure it's what the OP intends. He says he is referring to a language center, not the Korean peninsula, so it may be that the peninsula in question is not so anaphoric after all.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the second sentence. Well, yes, if it's available in the context, like somebody mentioned it, or somebody's pointing to it or a picture of it.

Comment: @John Lawler - Professor, in this Wikipedia example, "In the sentence 'Sally arrived, but nobody saw her,'  the pronoun her is anaphoric" Could you explain how "her" is anaphoric?

Comment: All pronouns are anaphoric. Anaphors are just words that are presupposed to refer to the same individual thing, like _Sally_ and _her_ in that sentence. The general term is _[Anaphora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_(linguistics))_.

Answer (score 2):

One definition of *there* is "in or at that place" ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/there)).

M-W gives some example sentences:

> - Stand over **there**. [Stand **in that place**.]
> - Put the package **there** on the table. [Put the package **in that place** on the table.
> - Turn **there** at the church. [Turn **at that place** at the church.]

So when you say "My cousins learned Korean there," it's a perfectly grammatically correct way of saying "My cousins learned Korean in that place." As long as a previous sentence has made it clear that *there* refers to the specific place of the language center, then your sentence is semantically correct as well.